# How can website server recognize incoming Tor or VPN connection?

Tags: anonymity, vpn, blocked-services

I was trying to signup for a service provided by a website using Tor, the website prevented me and asked me to disable my proxy settings, he noticed me with the following:

> Our checks indicate that you are connecting through a proxy at the moment. Please disable your proxy settings first and then try again. Thank you!

Then I tried a VPN connection with normal browser without any proxy settings, but the website still gives me the same notice.

My question is:

1. How can the website server detect my anonymity-based connection (Tor or VPN), what is the interpretation?
2. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The list of exit nodes is [well known](https://check.torproject.org/exit-addresses) so it's trivial for any system to look up into that list and see if any incoming connection comes from any of them.

Comment: Similarly, many VPNs can be detected by well-known exit servers and/or by extra HTTP headers inserted into requests by the VPN. Not foolproof by any means, and detectability will vary with different VPNs.